# How can I add an environment entry for _all_ project targets?

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, clion, library-path

In CLion (e.g. 2021.3), you can "Edit Configurations..." for project targets, and set environment variables (such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). But - how can I append such variables for *all* targets in a project? (That is, other than manually adding them for each target, or setting the environment variable before running CLion, both of which I want to avoid)?

Comment: I'd rather build with correct rpath than mess with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @Genjutsu: Actually, I agree, but somehow, CMake doesn't ensure the correct rpath when you have it detect a CUDA version that's not the system standard.